# Изи парсинг Python + lxml по XPath

Tags: html, python, парсер, xpath, lxml

Всем привет. Ума не приложу в чем проблема, пожалуйста помогите =)

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = 'https://ru.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSDT/technicals/'
body = requests.get(url).content

#lxml
tree = html.fromstring(body)
signal = tree.xpath('//span[contains(text(),"Статистика")]/following-sibling::span') 
print(signal)
```

**Вывод:**

> ```
> []
> ```

Сам путь XPath составлялся и проверялся со всеми необходимыми утилитами, дополнениями, знаниями и опытом. Ради проверки забивал другие XPath пути в строку signal - есть признаки жизни только когда тупо пишу `//div` или что то в это роде. Чуть более сложные конструкции с указанием класса или `id` например не воспринимаются. Возвращает пустой список.

**Что не так я делаю, спасите помогите, спасибо!**

Comment: Как будто я не правильно обращаюсь с модулем, или я даже не знаю....

Comment: В коде страницы нет слова «Статистика». Оно добавляется на страницу джаваскриптом

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо за наметку. Буду разбираться в этом направлении.

Comment: @andreymal Интересно что если я использую, например следующий Xpath путь, то получаю пустой список снова

    //div[@id="technicals-root"]/descendant::span

Почему такое может быть не подскажете, тут ведь не может быть никак виноват JS предполагаю. Например  //div[@id="technicals-root"] находит но стоит начать уточнять путь как снова натыкаюсь на пустой список. При работе в Зенопостере таких проблем не встречал, поэтому предполагаю что дело в чем то другом...Но не могу понять в чем

Comment: В коде страницы написано `<div id="technicals-root" style="min-height:600px;"></div>` — нету тут никаких span. Да и вообще ничего нету, кроме самого div. Видимо, опять JS вмешивается

Comment: Зенопостер работает на базе браузеров, а у браузеров есть JS. lxml — это не браузер, и у него нету JS

Comment: @andreymal Большое спасибо за объяснения, теперь все понятно. Поэксперементировав с другими сайтами понял, что Вы точно правы. Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: Почитайте про selenium webdriver - оно использует браузеры и с js всё хорошо

Comment: @andreymal я прямо вот в ногу иду с Вашими советами. Сегодня весь день селениум изучал, через него получается лучше искать запрятанные элементы)